# Execute procedure for a bunch of values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which takes the value from the ID-Column of one table (which has about 900 entries) as an input to perform the actions needed. Is there an easy way to execute the stored procedure for all values of the ID-column by an SQL-Statement (similar to a for-loop which doesn't exist in SQL)?

Thanks for hints!

Melvin

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate an attempted effort. Show us your current code and what you've tried.

Comment: You can use a cursor or `WHILE` loop but best to rewrite the stored procedure to accept a TVP and deal with it in a set based way.

Comment: Since you will have to run your proc 900 times, I would say instead of going by loop or cursor; you can use SSIS which would be better in performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Martin,

I go for the cursor version and it works fast enough:

```
DECLARE @ProID int
DECLARE position_cursor CURSOR
    FOR SELECT ProID FROM MyTable
OPEN position_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM position_cursor INTO @ProID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   exec MyProcedure @ProID
   FETCH NEXT FROM position_cursor INTO @ProID
END
CLOSE position_cursor
DEALLOCATE position_cursor
```